# How to get the address of a returned rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>
int&& func() {return 7;}
int main() {
  std::cout << &func();
}
```

Produces an error, even with `return std::move(7)`. It's saying func() is an rvalue (as if I'm doing &7).

Comment: Well yes, it's an rvalue. And a dangling reference. How are you planning to use the address?

Comment: **Don't**.  It is always a mistake to return a reference to a function local non-static variable/literal.

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to get an rvalue reference to the return value but cdecl calling convention passes the return value in eax so maybe it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

> It's saying func() is an rvalue

Well, it *is* an rvalue.

> (as if I'm doing &7).

It *is* as if you're doing `&7`, at least in the sense that you can't use `&` on an rvalue.

In reality you're trying to use a dangling reference to a temporary `int` (initialised from a literal) as an lvalue.

This code makes no sense. I don't know what you're trying to do, but you can't do it.

Comment: Yes, it would be a dangling reference but I was still expecting it to compile. For instance, 7 could be pushed on the stack and the address of 7 returned in `eax` if the return type is int&&, so really I was asking why this is disallowed when you're allowed to get the address of an lvalue reference to a local variable as a return value (which is also dangling)

Comment: @JohnSmith You're not allowed to get the address of an rvalue. You've never been allowed to get the address of an rvalue. It's not clear to me why you thought you would be permitted to get the address of an rvalue, or why you'd ever _want_ to get the address of an rvalue. The stack/registers are irrelevant; you are writing C++, not programming a processor chip. Also, making comparisons with undefined programs is not a strong argument.

Comment: You can get the address of an rvalue through an rvalue reference though, just try `&&int a = 1; std::cout << &a;`. I'd have thought that the code in the question would have behaved in the same way. How is it irrelevant? It's fundamental perspective of higher-level programming languages; not thinking in that paradigm is pretty unimaginable.

Comment: @JohnSmith It's irrevelant because `&func()` doesn't work simply because the standard doesn't allow it, not because of how the processor works. Using the same trick you mentioned, you *can* get the address: `int *foo(int &&x){return &x;} ... std::cout << foo(func());`.

Comment: @JohnSmith An rvalue reference and an rvalue are two different things. `a` in your example is an lvalue. (If you correct `&&int` to `int`, that is). As for "fundamental paradigm"... well, no. Not at all. The _whole point_ of higher level languages is that stacks/registers are far abstracted away from you.